# Multiple click events firing on generated elements

Tags: jquery

I am confused because I've done something like this before but I am not understanding the outcome behavior at all.  I am generating `<li>` elements from a JSON list.  I am then (obviously) appending them to a `<ul>` element. Each `<li>` gets its own reference to a click event method I wrote.  For some reason, whenever I click an item, it starts triggering multiple click events.  It's behaving as if each item is being assigned all of the events for other items.  However, I thought the below code was not supposed to behave that way.  Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

`Item and Click event generation:`

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.Spellbook, function (index, spell) {
        $("#Spellbook").append(
            $("<li />").on("click", ViewSpell(spell.Id, CharacterID, ClassId, data.SpellLevel, true))
            .addClass("selector").text(spell.Name)
        );
    });
},
```

`Click Event:`

```
var ViewSpell = (function (SpellId, CharacterId, ClassId, SpellLevel, CanBeDeleted) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url.SpellDetails,
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            SpellId: SpellId,
            CharacterId: CharacterId,
            ClassId: ClassId,
            SpellLevel: SpellLevel,
            CanBeDeleted: CanBeDeleted
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#SpellDetails").html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, state, thrownError) {
            $("#SpellDetails").html(JSON.stringify(xhr));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should just append the elements and separately listen to 'clicks'. Append a li, have a jquery $('li').on('click',function(){...});

Comment: So you're saying I put that at the end of my "success"?
I'm still curious as to why the behavior I describe is happening, because I've created elements before and assigned click events to each one in a for loop without this behavior happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are invoking the `ViewSpell` and passing its return value. Since you are using `$.each()` its executing multiple times

I would recommend you to store data which need to be passed to `ViewSpell` in data cache. Which can be stored and fetched using `$.fn.data()`

```
$.each(data.Spellbook, function (index, spell) {
    var li = $("<li />")
        .addClass("selector")
        .text(spell.Name)
        .data('spell', spell)
        .data('characterid', CharacterID)
        .data('classid', ClassId)           
        .on("click", function(){
            var s = $(this).data('spell');
            ViewSpell(s.Id, $(this).data('characterid'), $(this).data('classid'), s.SpellLevel, true);
        });

    $("#Spellbook").append(li);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to make sense.  I figured since they were both functions, that I didn't need to put the function inside a "callback" function like that.  But I understand why.  If I had just done ViewSpell, without the parenthesis, that wouldn't have happened, but I obviously was needing to pass some parameters to it. Thanks for the solution and the additional suggestions.